# Como realizar consulta em duas tabelas fazendo combinação de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo duas tabelas:

**material**

```
id | categoria | subcategoria | codigo
1  |     3     | 15           | FS-5600
2  |     0     | 16           | FA-4500
```

**subcategoria**

```
id  | descricao | id_categoria | id_produto
1   |  Alasca   | 3            | 2
4   |  Aragon   | 3            | 2
16  |  A. Luiza | 7            | 1
15  |  Astoria  | 8            | 1
```

Possuo um campo de pesquisa, onde o usuário pode buscar tanto pela descrição, quanto pelo código. Como podemos ver, codigo e descricao estão em tabelas separadas, porém ao realizar uma determinada pesquisa, preciso que ambos sejam retornados.

Como deve ser montada a *query*?

Comment: Mas voce quer que retorne o quê? Produto? Descrição da subcategoria?

Comment: @DanilloVictor, descrição e seu respectivo código.

Comment: a coluna código está referenciando qual coluna da tabela subcategoria?

Comment: @DanilloVictor, podemos continuar essa discussão via [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67071/como-realizar-consulta-em-duas-tabelas-fazendo-combinacao-de-dados)?

Comment: Sua pergunta não ficou clara, o que deve pesquisar? o que devo retornar para determinada pesquisa?

Comment: Pedro, desejo retornar código e descrição. **"Como podemos ver, codigo e descricao estão em tabelas separadas, porém ao realizar uma determinada pesquisa, preciso que ambos sejam retornados."** @PedroH.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o inner join, é um recurso comum para esses casos.

Comment: o erro está dizendo que não existe a coluna codigo na tabela subcategoria.
Por isso estou dizendo, a coluna código da tabela material está referenciando qual coluna da tabela subcategoria?

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem a pergunta você quer que o usuário digite um termo em um campo de busca e o sistema traga tanto os códigos como as descrições que coincidam com a pesquisa.

Supondo que a ligação entre as tabelas seja id e id_produto

```
SELECT * FROM material as m JOIN subcategoria a s ON m.id = s.id_produto WHERE m.codigo LIKE 'termoAPesquisar%' OR s.descricao LIKE 'termoAPesquisar%';
```

Voce tambem pode ligar o JOIN pelas colunas codigo.subcategoria e subcategoria.id, mas nesse caso quando a consulta for por código do produto o sistema não retornará todas as subcategorias. Então pelas infos que passou e pelo que entendi acho que o ideal é a ligaçao por id_produto